# Linux script start,stop,restart

Tags: linux

Can anyone please tell me what exactly this script does?

```
#! /bin/sh
test –f /usr/bin/sshd || exit 0
case “$1” in
    start)
            echo –n “Starting sshd: sshd”
            /usr/sbin/sshd
            echo “.”
            ;;
   stop) 
          echo –n “Stopping sshd: sshd”
          kill `cat /var/run/sshd.pid`
          echo “.”
           ;;
   restart)
          echo –n “Stopping sshd: sshd”
          kill `cat /var/run/sshd.pid`
          echo “.”
          echo –n “Starting sshd: sshd”
            /usr/sbin/sshd
            echo “.”
            ;;
        *)
          echo “Usage: /etc/init.d/sshd start|stop|restart”
          exit 1
          ;;
    esac
```

I want to know what exactly this part:

```
#! /bin/sh
test –f /usr/bin/sshd || exit 0
case “$1” in
    start)
            echo –n “Starting sshd: sshd”
            /usr/sbin/sshd
            echo “.”
            ;;
```

does because the other part is the same!
Please ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Which other part is the same? The way that script works is it checks the value of `$1`, which is the first parameter to the script supplied on the command-line. If it's 'start', then the part after `start)` is executed. If it's 'stop', then the part after `stop)` is executed. If it's 'restart', then the part after `restart)` is executed.

Line by line for that first part:

```
#! /bin/sh
```

Hey, it's a shell script! Specifically, execute this script using the `sh` shell.

```
test –f /usr/bin/sshd || exit 0
```

Is there a file called `/usr/bin/sshd`? If not, exit with a 0 return status.

```
case “$1” in
```

Check the value of `$1`, the first command-line option.

```
    start)
```

If `$1` is 'start'...

```
            echo –n “Starting sshd: sshd”
```

Print "`Starting sshd: sshd`".

```
            /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Execute `/usr/sbin/sshd`.

```
            echo “.”
```

Print "`.`".

```
            ;;
```

Exit the `case` statement.

Answer (score 1):

sshd writes its process ID to the file in /var/run.  The backticks  cause the script inside them to be executed by the shell, and the result is used in its place.

The net result is    kill [sshd pid]

Answer (score 1):

The part you mention starts the "sshd" program. It's the Secure Shell (SSH) daemon (server process).

Depending on the command-line argument, your script starts, stops or restarts the SSH server. `$1` represents the command-line argument, and this value gets compared to the different possible values between `case` and `esac`.

Answer (score 1):

The `test –f /usr/bin/sshd` part returns `true` if the file exists. The `||` is an **or**, so the `|| exit 0` gets executed (ending the script) only if the first part returned false.

In the `case "$1"` part, the `$1` is the first argument passed to the script.

Answer (score 1):

*"I want to know what exactly this part... does because the other part is the same!"*

**start)** assumes that sshd is not already started, and starts it.

This is different from **restart)**, which first stops the sshd process (as Joe describes), and then starts it again.