# Start stop restart linux script like well known programs (apache,openvpn,squid etc)

Tags: bash

Does anyone know a tutorial how to control the execution of a script (created) like we control squid, the basic run and stop command?
**Example:**
    `#squid start;`
     `#squid stop;`
     `#squid restart;`

Comment: Take a look at how the scripts in `/etc/init.d` are written, and just copy that style.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
cmd=$1
case "$cmd" in
start)
    # code to start the service
    ;;
stop)
    # code to stop the service
    ;;
restart)
    # code to restart
    ;;
...
*) echo Invalid command: "$cmd"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: thanks for responding, i was aware of this step but I am more interested on the code on this cases. I am interested on the gray line:  # code to restart. I have found this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797717/linux-script-start-stop-restart

Comment: That depends on the particular application.

Comment: I'm talking for a simple bash script, "switch.sh" that i have created and is working fine. I want this solution for special cases when system blocks or just want to stop it running for a while

Comment: start just runs the script. stop can use `pkill` or `killall` to find the script and kill it.

Comment: `root  1399   1  0 10:56 ? 00:00:00 /bin/bash /root/switch.sh` this is the output of ` ps -ef` how can i kill it without having the PID number. I saw that squid have a squid.pid that use to write the current pid values, and than call kill 'cat squid.pid '

Comment: `pkill` and `killall` allow you to give a program name and they'll find the PID.

Comment: I will try thanks. this code will work if i add it directly on the main script, even on first running?