# How can I make a bash script start, stop and restart in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a script to run java applications on ubuntu

```
nohup java -Xms512m -Xmx8g -jar /data/software/190716/myapp-0.0.1.jar --server.port=8080 --spring.config.location=/data/software/myapp.properties > ~/running.myapp.log &
```

can I make a `.sh` script to make the command start, stop and restart the process?
thanks

Comment: Just a guess, Possible you can find an answer from [Stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797717/linux-script-start-stop-restart)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/944244/running-a-java-process-from-systemd

Comment: maybe this can help, you can get the answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/33641/bash-script-to-start-and-then-shutdown-restart-various-processes

Comment: Or pick any script in /etc/init.d/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the better way to do that follow [running-a-java-process-from-systemd](https://superuser.com/questions/944244/running-a-java-process-from-systemd)

But if you are really interested in a bash script, then you can do something like this, but keep in mind there is might be a better approach for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

function start_app() {

    # tested with this , uncomment your command
    nohup node bin/www > logfile.txt  2>&1 & 
    # nohup java -Xms512m -Xmx8g -jar /data/software/190716/myapp-0.0.1.jar --server.port=8080 --spring.config.location=/data/software/myapp.properties
    # write the pid to text to file to use it later
    app_pid=$!
    echo "Process started having PID $app_pid"
    # wait for process to check proper state, you can change this time accordingly 
    sleep 3
    if ps -p $app_pid > /dev/null
    then
        echo "Process successfully running having PID $app_pid"
        # write if success
        echo $app_pid > process_id.txt
    else
        echo "Process stopped before reached to steady state"
    fi
}

function stop_app() {
    # Get the PID from text file
    application_pid=$(cat process_id.txt)
    echo "stopping process, Details:"
    # print details
    ps -p $application_pid
    # check if running
    if ps -p $application_pid > /dev/null
    then
        # if running then kill else print message
        echo "Going to stop process having PId $application_pid"
        kill -9 $application_pid
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Process stopped successfully"
        else
        echo "Failed to stop process having PID $application_pid"
        fi
    else
        echo "Failed to stop process, Process is not running"
    fi
}


case "$1" in 
    start_app)   start_app ;;
    stop_app)    stop_app ;;
    restart) stop_app; start_app ;;
    *) echo "usage: $0 start_app|stop_app|restart_app" >&2
       exit 1
       ;;
esac
```

[image]

Comment: why down vote? any reason if this the requirement of the user then we should respond accordingly?

Comment: apparently can, I'm very grateful, but I remove the spurious CR characters with sed -i -e 's/\r$//'

Comment: ohh, btw can I add many script "nohup . . ." in the .sh file?

Comment: yes you can add but then modification will be required on script, to keep ID of process for different `nohup`